# Array does not keep previous elements after being updated

Tags: php, symfony

Job entity has a property called candidates which is an array of Users and it is **not** mapped or related to any other entity.On given route we fetch specific Job object by id.We update our candidates array by assigning the user who we get from the current session.It turns out that the user is being saved, but on each call we lose those users which had been saved before.

Why does that happen?

```
/**
 * @Route("/job/apply/{id}", requirements={"id"="\d+"}, name="student_candidate", methods={"POST"})
 *
 * @param int $id
 *
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function apply(int $id)
{
    $job = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Job::class)->find($id);
    $candidate = $this->getUser();
    $job->addCandidate($candidate);
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

    return new JsonResponse([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'some_success_message'
    ]);
}
```

```
class Job
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", length=65535)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var User[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    private $candidates;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->candidates = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return User[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getCandidates()
    {
        return $this->candidates;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function addCandidate(User $user)
    {
        $this->candidates[] = $user;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would assume, that no user ever is saved, because the field is not mapped as you correctly pointed out. since you add the current user on each request, the user itself is there (temporarily until the end of the request) but since candidates is not mapped, there is no saving. Maybe I misunderstand your question, but what do expect for an unmapped field (read: virtual / non-persisted)

Comment: Oh, right.I should map it and it would probably work.By mapping it I should choose one of the relationship, right? Is ManyToMany unidirectional the correct approach?One job can have many candidates and many candidates can have many jobs, right?

Comment: ManyToMany is correct, yes. make sure you create the appropriate join table.